# simple testing of semaphores

Tags: unix, testing, shared-memory, semaphore, multiprocess

I am trying to create a simple program to test semaphores. I am forking the process and tormenting the value of variable c in the critical section of each process, but the value of c I get is still 1 not 2. Even with the mmap() uncommented. Can anyone please explain to me what I am doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated. I am a total newbie in this. Thank you very much for your time.

```
int main()
{
int c = 0;
  sem_t mutex;
 sem_t mutex1;
 //  sem_t *mutex = (sem_t*)mmap(NULL, sizeof(sem_t*), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS,-1, 0);
 sem_init(&mutex, 0, 1);
 sem_init(&mutex1, 0, 1);

  pid_t i;
  int id = fork();
 if(id == -1)   {}
  else if(id == 0)
    {
    sem_wait (&mutex);  
   c++;
   sem_post (&mutex);
   }
   else
  {
    sem_wait (&mutex);  
   c++;
   sem_post (&mutex);
   }    
     cout<<c<<endl;
   //system("pause");
   return 0;
    }
```

I tried it another way by making the pshared argument 1, but it still does not work. 
I have also tried it sem_op but it still does not work.

```
 int main()
    {


      int c = 0;


           int sid =semget(1105,2, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);


        pid_t i;
      int id = fork();

       if(id == -1)
       {

        }
            else if(id == 0)
           {

                struct sembuf sb;
                sb.sem_num = 0;
                sb.sem_op = -1;
                sb.sem_flg = 0;
                  if((semop(sid, &sb, 1)) == -1)
            cout<<"error"<<endl;

                    c++;

                sb.sem_num = 0;
                sb.sem_op = -1;
                sb.sem_flg = 0;

                      if((semop(sid, &sb, 1)) == -1)
          cout<<"error"<<endl;

         }
         else if(id == 1)
         {

                   struct sembuf sb;

                  if((semop(sid, &sb, 1)) == -1)
            cout<<"error"<<endl;

                    c++;


                     sb.sem_num = 0;
                    sb.sem_op = -1;
                    sb.sem_flg = 0;

                      if((semop(sid, &sb, 1)) == -1)
          cout<<"error"<<endl;

          }

            cout<<c<<endl;

          return 0;

            }
```

Comment: Please take the time to properly format the code you posted.

Comment: Please run your code through [`indent(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/indent) or a similar function from your IDE — your hand edits are still inconsistently formatted and hard to follow.  Please include headers necessary for compilation.  Please exclude extraneous code like `mutex1`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [fork()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fork) you have to share the semaphores between the forked processes. See [sem_init() manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_init.3.html) for more details.

Alternatively you can use a named semaphore, see [sem_open()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_open) for details, and
also [a good article on the subject](http://blog.superpat.com/2010/07/14/semaphores-on-linux-sem_init-vs-sem_open/).

Comment: Yeah I did that, but it still does not work. I am running Linux mint 14. Do you think that could be a problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your primary misstep is that the variable `c` is not itself shared — each process operates on its own copy of the variable.  You want something like this:

```
int *c;

c = mmap(NULL, sizeof(*c), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
*c = 0;

// ... later ...
++*c;
```

Additionally, with respect to your `sem_init()` example, you should:

- Allocate shared memory of the correct size:  `sizeof(sem_t)` and *not* `sizeof(sem_t*)`
- Set the *pshared* flag during `sem_init()`

You likely don't need conditional logic differentiating parent from child after the `fork()`.  After all, you want them to do the same thing.

(Separately, please do not name a POSIX semaphore "mutex."  That name will mislead hurried, POSIXly-minded folk who will think you are referring to a different kind of synchronization primitive.)

With respect to your `semget()` example, you appear to be waiting on the semaphore twice (`sb.sem_op = -1`) in the child process.  The post-`fork()` check for the parent is incorrect — you check if the returned PID is 1 (which it will never be on a typical UNIX system) rather than if the returned PID is > 0.  (Again, however, you likely don't need to have parent and child do different things here.)